# onchange function is called only once for newly create element

Tags: javascript, html

A function creates an element and appends it to a parent. The element in question contains other elements among which there is an input checkbox. I add an event listener to the onchange event. For the sake of brevity the listener only writes 'here' to the console. Upon loading the page the first time the 'here' message appears and this makes sense because the checked attribute was set to true. The problem is that the listener will not be triggered by any click after that. Can anyone shed light on this?

```
    function createNewRow(number){
        var row=document.createElement('div');
        automaticLegend.appendChild(row);
        var txt=document.createTextNode('Particle '+number);
        var showBtn=document.createElement('input');
        showBtn.type='checkbox';
        showBtn.checked=true;
        var labelShow=document.createTextNode('Show ');
        var traceBtn=document.createElement('input');
        traceBtn.type='checkbox';
        traceBtn.checked=true;
        var labelTrace=document.createTextNode('Trace ');
        var radiusBtn=document.createElement('input');
        radiusBtn.type='checkbox';
        radiusBtn.checked=true;
        var labelRadius=document.createTextNode('Radius ');
        var delBtn=document.createElement('input');
        delBtn.type='button';
        delBtn.value='Remove';
        row.appendChild(txt);
        row.appendChild(showBtn);
        row.appendChild(labelShow)
        row.appendChild(traceBtn);
        row.appendChild(labelTrace);
        row.appendChild(radiusBtn);
        row.appendChild(labelRadius);
        row.appendChild(delBtn);
        showBtn.onchange=resetShowFlag(showBtn);
};
function resetShowFlag(el){
    console.log('here');
}
```

Comment: `showBtn.onchange=function(){resetShowFlag(showBtn);};`

Comment: you must assign a function, `resetShowFlag(showBtn)` is a function-call, not a function. It will be executed immediately and not when the event will be triggered.

Comment: Try this: `window.onDirty=alert('clean me!')` , of course there is no such event, but you'll see the alert

Answer (score 0):

try to use this.
showBtn.addEventListener('change', resetShowFlag);